# DataTables Filtering on Alt Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, filtering

Using DataTables 1.10.19 and [this plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/alt-string), I am using the `alt` attribute as the data to sort upon.

This works;

```
{
    targets: [7],
    type: 'alt-string',
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (data == 1) {
            return '<a href="example.com"><i class="icon-ok" alt="Processed"></i></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work;

```
{
    targets: [7],
    type: 'alt-string',
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (data == 1) {
            return '<a href="example.com?id=' + row[0] + '&approvalcode=' + row[9] + '"><i class="icon-ok" alt="Processed"></i></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Seems t be when I add in the `row` URL query strings it breaks the `alt` filter, although everything else works as expected.

Plugin code is below;

```
/**
 * Sort on the 'alt' tag of images in a column. This is particularly useful if
 * you have a column of images (ticks and crosses for example) and you want to
 * control the sorting using the alt tag.
 *
 *  @name Alt string
 *  @summary Use the `alt` attribute of an image tag as the data to sort upon.
 *  @author _Jumpy_
 *
 *  @example
 *    $('#example').dataTable( {
 *       columnDefs: [
 *         { type: 'alt-string', targets: 0 }
 *       ]
 *    } );
 */

jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "alt-string-pre": function ( a ) {
        return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
    },

    "alt-string-asc": function( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "alt-string-desc": function(a,b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

Comment: Can you show a better code excerpt from your html and how you initialize the data tables and plugin.

Comment: Alright, take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tarip/xpvt214o/953703/) and tell me if that'S what you want. Ofc you have to adjust the rows targeted and your data will be something different. But i guess you could just get the `row[wherevermylinkisindex]`

Comment: Alright last try for now. If condition is true it'll render the link with query params and alt tag. Sorting by alt will work. Switched to codepen cause fiddle kinda shredded my memory. [Example](https://codepen.io/Tarip/pen/xQpbqr?)

Answer (score 0):

Inital value of first column will be `0` or `1`. If the value is `1` a link with query parameters is inserted and the `<i>` will get the `alt="Processed"`. Otherwise the link will be inserted without  parameters and the alt value will be `"Not Processed"`. Rendered table will then be ordered by the alt attributes of the `<i>` inside the first column. I also just concatenate the html string with `+`. I parse the data value to int since it is handed as a string. If i don't do this it will never append the query parameters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      {
        type: "alt-string",
        targets: 0,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          if (parseInt(data) === 1) {
            return (
              '<a href="www.example.com?id=' +
              row[2] +
              "&approvalcode=" +
              row[3] +
              '"><i class="icon-ok" alt="Processed">link' +
              row[2] +
              "</i></a>"
            );
          } else {
            return (
              '<a href="www.example.com"><i class="icon-ok" alt="New">link' +
              row[2] +
              "</i></a>"
            );
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/alt-string.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Condition</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1007</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>7001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1337</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>80085</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Condition</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: So in your example, searching for 'processed' should display those results where the condition = `1`? Because this doesn't work.

Comment: The above example is just showing the sorting by alt tags of dynamically rendered content, not the filtering/search. You can search for the links names but not the alt tags.

Comment: If you need to make the search work, maybe take a look into [Custom filtering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).